# Python count number of digits for a value lower 1

Tags: python

What is the easiest way in python to count the number of digits after the decimal point for a value < 1 without using string-functions?

For example i have one of the following values: 0.0001 or 0.1001 or 0.1234.

The result in all cases should be 4.

Comment: try `math.log10(0.0001)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You'll get the same answer for `0.000111`, but I think the OP wants 6 for that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what about 0.002 or 0.00111? ;)

Comment: you're right. Misread

Comment: unless when using string conversions, the question makes no sense as `0.1234` is a string representation of the number.

Comment: for instance try with `0.2999999999999999999`

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
>>> x, i = 0.345223, 0
>>> while x*(10**i)//1 - x*(10**i) != 0: i+= 1
... 
>>> i
6
```

Comment: Floating point inaccuracy is likely to produce anomalous results in many cases.

Comment: @Barmar For sure.

Comment: we can use `str` function i.e.
```len(str(x).split('.')[-1])
```

Comment: @sleeping_coder op asked for non string functions

Answer (score 0):

You could do a quick math trick and multiply by 10 until the number is equal to 1 or greater:

```
i
0.0001

count
0

while i < 1:
i = i*10
  count += 1

count
4
```

Comment: This is the number of zeroes after the decimal point, not the number of digits.

Comment: Another answer can be found (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189956/easy-way-of-finding-decimal-places]

Comment: my question was not exact enough, i corrected it now.

Comment: for clarification: this *only* works for numbers between 0 and 1, and will not count values after the first non-zero in the decimal.