# Finding the amount of digits after the decimal point

Tags: python, digits

Im trying to make a function that returns the amount of digits pass the decimal point
I dont know what to do.

So for example

- 5.67 returns 2 digits
- 5.159 returns 3 digits
- 5.000 returns 0 digits

I have tried to use the round() function but that doesnt work

Any suggestions?

My code so far
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8IFj.png)

Comment: You can only do this using string functions, not numeric functions.

Comment: Post your code as text, not a screenshot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easy way of finding decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189956/easy-way-of-finding-decimal-places)

Answer (score 0):

how is this? Please let me know :)

```
def get_num_digits_after_point(num):
    newNum = str(num)

    should_I_count = False
    count = 0
    for char in newNum:
        if char == '.':
            should_I_count = True
        elif should_I_count:
            count += 1

    q = False
    NEWcount = 0
    d = 0
    for i in newNum:
        if i == '.':
            q = True
        elif q:
            d += 1
            if i == '0':
                NEWcount += 1
    # print(NEWcount)
    # print(d)
    if NEWcount == d:
        return 0
    else:
        return count


print(get_num_digits_after_point(5.67))
print(get_num_digits_after_point(5.159))
print(get_num_digits_after_point(5.001))
print(get_num_digits_after_point(5.000))
```

Comment: `get_num_digits_after_point(5.001)` returns 1.  Shouldn't answer be 3?

Comment: Can u explain this real quickly?

Comment: DarryIG, it should return 3

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it :)

Comment: Btw, i need to make seperate function for when the number has 1 digit, 2 digit, 3 digit or 0 digit pass the decimal points

Comment: what the For Char in the function mean?

Comment: It goes though every character in the string

Comment: ok real quick if u can, can you explain it in words, the function

Comment: @JohnWilliams--are you sayingyou need separate functions--one for 0 digits, one for 1 digits, one for 2 digit, etc.?

Comment: @helloworld14751 Yes

Comment: ? Anyone has anything?

Comment: I just need how to check if 1 digit is pass the decimcal points?