# Pad float with zeros according to maximum length in list

Tags: python, list, zero-padding

I have a list:

```
ls = [1.0, 2.11, 3.981329, -15.11]
```

I want to add zeros to decimal places of each element so that all values have the same length as the value that has maximum length. So the output should be:

```
[1.000000, 2.110000, 3.981329, -15.110000]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You will have to use strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a floating number to fixed width in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python)

Comment: And: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189956/easy-way-of-finding-decimal-places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution. Note that the nums will be strings:

```
ls = [1.0, 2.11, 3.981329, -15.11]

dps = lambda x: len(x) - x.index(".") - 1

max_dp = max([dps(str(i)) for i in ls])

new_ls = [f"%.{max_dp}f"%i for i in ls]

print(new_ls)
```

Output:

```
['1.000000', '2.110000', '3.981329', '-15.110000']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily output to a desired number of decimal places,

```
print("["+", ".join(f"{el:.8f}" for el in ls)+"]")
```

using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).

The value of getting the maximum number of visible decimal places is something you might want to consider carefully - it isn't obvious why you would do that in a simulated raw output like this. You can get a suitable number by a string analysis but it isn't pretty.

```
dp = 0
for el in ls:
    op = str(el)
    if "." in op:
        dpi = len(op)-1 - op.find(".")
        if dpi > dp: dp = dpi
print("["+", ".join(f"{el:.{dp}f}" for el in ls)+"]")
```