# How can I find float numbers that have more than two decimals? (Python)

Tags: python, filter, floating-point, decimal

I need a solution to access all numbers that have more than two decimals.
e.g.

Have:

```
nums = [0.95, 0.7, 0.0, 0.3234, 0.54563]
```

Need:

```
many_decimals = [0.3234, 0.54563]
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This problem is not well defined. Most multiples of 0.01 cannot be exactly stored as floating-point numbers, although if a number is sufficently close to an exact multiple of 0.01 then python will output only two decimals when converting them to a string. So you will need to define more closely what is meant by having more than two decimals. I would tend to suggest defining some tolerance margin explicitly, rather than just relying on what `str` does with them (which could be implementation-dependent), but that's a choice that you will need to make in defining the problem.

Comment: If you do `import decimal; a=0.95; print(decimal.Decimal(a))`, you will see a decimal representation of the exact number that is stored internally, and that it is not equal to 0.95, even though if you just do `print(a)` it will output `0.95`.

When I try it, I get `0.9499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875`, although this may be implementation-dependent, as it depends on the mantissa width (essentially, the number of bits used to store floating point numbers).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to string, reverse the string, then get index of '.' in the string which is the count of decimal places.

Try something like this:

```
nums = [0.95, 0.7, 0.0, 0.3234, 0.54563]
print([f for f in nums if str(f)[::-1].find('.') > 2])
```

**Output:**

```
[0.3234, 0.54563]
```

**Solution breakdown:**

```
s = str(0.54563)[::-1] # => '36545.0'
s.find('.')            # => 5
```

If the number is a whole integer (e.g. 100) then s.find('.') returns -1 so this still works for the case of checking more than 2 decimal places.

An alternative posted in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6190291/543969) uses the decimal package and the exponent property. Using this approach creates the same output as above.

```
import decimal
print([f for f in nums if abs(decimal.Decimal(str(f)).as_tuple().exponent) > 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

The fraction of the *exact* float number's value must end with: `0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75`.

Algorithm:

1. Extract the fraction.
2. Scaled by 4.0.
3. Test fraction against 0.0.

If non-zero, the original value needs more than 2 places for *exact* decimal representation.